# ansible not connect after fail accelerate mode

Tags: ansible

When I run ansible-playbook in accelerate mode and for some reason ansible task fail the next run will not connect with following error

```
PLAY [all] ******************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
fatal: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] => Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5099

TASK: [role | task] *********************************************** 
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting


PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @//task.retry

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx                : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   

PLAY [all] ******************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
fatal: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] => Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5099

TASK: [role | task] ********************************************* 
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

and so on...

Then in target host there is a ansible procces running. I run

```
kill -9 $(ps -aux | grep accelerate | awk '{print $2}')
```

for kill this proccess and next run success.

Somebody knows what happen and how fix it.

Comment: Does your server's firewall allow connections to 5099?

Comment: yes, first time running ok, and after kill process run ok too

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't the answer to your question, but why use accelerate mode when you can enable `ControlMaster` for SSH. It should work faster that accelerate mode in most of the cases and you don't have to worry about opening one more port. Just add the following into ansible.cfg:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s
```